# Creating DataBase using Realm Swift 3.0.1

Tags: swift, database, xcode, object, realm

How to create Realm DB? I have installed Realm by CocoaPods for swift(>=3.0). I'm trying to create a simple DB that will be keep max 20 objects. I have create a class DataBase():

```
import RealmSwift

class DataBase: Object{    
    dynamic var code: String = ""
    dynamic var desc: String = ""
    dynamic var capture: [UIImage] = []
    dynamic var lon: Double = 0.0
    dynamic var lat: Double = 0.0
    dynamic var type: Int = 0    
}
```

And I want to add an object to DB:

```
 let offlineInfo = DataBase()

 let realm = try! Realm()

 offlineInfo.code = "testCode"
 offlineInfo.desc = "testDescription"
 offlineInfo.capture = self.capture
 offlineInfo.lat = self.lat
 offlineInfo.lon = self.lon
 offlineInfo.type = 2

 try! realm.write {
            realm.add(offlineInfo)
        }
```

But I have a SIGABRT error when creating "offlineInfo" object and don't sure that I'm doing it correctly. And are the DB will save even I exit from the app?

Comment: Can you add the exact error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely

```
dynamic var capture: [UIImage] = []
```

is a problem: Realm doesn't support storing `UIImage` directly.

There are two options here: either to store `NSData` representation of images or store images on disk but keep paths to them in database.

Learn more about supported data types in [Docs](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#supported-types).